# What is the best way to prioritize information, with your team colleagues?

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, interface, information-architecture, user-centered-design

I intend to do a group activity here in my company to list the avaliable information in an e-commerce product page. Example: buy button, product image, product description, other users comments etc.

We want to order it by priority, from the most important to the last.

What are the best tools/ methods to make it, involving the entire team?

I heard about Affinity Diagram and Card Sorting, but I want to hear more from experts =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Card sorting is an excellent way to group information into intelligent buckets, but for prioritizing there are variations that use card sorting as well:

http://goodkickoffmeetings.com/2010/04/prioritization-card-sort/

You might also try something like "group brainwriting" where you write all of the elements on a white board, then give everyone in the room a column in a shared google doc or something and tell them they have 3 minutes to enter all of the elements into their column in order of priority. Then you see how well those correlate. The benefit of this is that there's less setup time required and it can take as little as 3-5 minutes to run the actual test.

Either way, however, it would be best to all have a shared understanding of both the business goals and the user goals before starting. Here's some more reading for you:

http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2013/12/the-best-ways-to-prioritize-products-and-features.php